# Facebook app with error

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm not a Facebook App expert. I grabbed this code from the FB website and I modified it to make it work with my app id (it is the only thing I changed. I added a couple of alerts too). Then I tried to use this code from a local webpage (that is: the page is on my desktop but my laptop is connected to the Internet).

Anytime I run this code I get a browser popup showing this error:
"An error occurred with MyAppName. Please try again later."

Can someone tell me what's going on here? It seems the FB.getLoginStatus never gets called too.

Any help is appreciated.

```
// initialize the library with the API key
FB.init({ appId: 'myAppID',frictionlessRequests:true });

// fetch the status on load
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
// the user is logged in and has authenticated your
// app, and response.authResponse supplies
// the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
// request, and the time the access token 
// and signed request each expire
var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
alert("1. not");
// the user is logged in to Facebook, 
// but has not authenticated your app
} else {
alert("2. alert");
// the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
}
});

$('#login').bind('click', function() {
FB.login(handleSessionResponse);
});

$('#logout').bind('click', function() {
FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
});

$('#disconnect').bind('click', function() {
FB.api({ method: 'Auth.revokeAuthorization' }, function(response) {
clearDisplay();
});
});

// no user, clear display
function clearDisplay() {
$('#user-info').hide('fast');
}

// handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
function handleSessionResponse(response) {
// if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
alert("entered handleSessionResponse");
if (response.authResponse) {
alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
});
} else {
alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
if (!response.session) {
clearDisplay();
return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the property `myAppID` to the ID of the Facebook app you are using?

```
FB.init({ appId: 'myAppID',frictionlessRequests:true });
```

The `myAppID` should contain a unique Facebook App ID which you can fetch on the Facebook App page. Maybe you just copied the code without changing this.